# error in running elasticsearch batch file

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run elasticsearch batch file through CLI but there is an error:
warning: ignoring JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20; using bundled JDK
Error: could not open `E:\Download\xampp_ins\htdocs\elasticsearch-8.9.2\jdk\lib\jvm.cfg'

I tried setting Java_Home path to jdk directory of elastic search but it did not work.